# Escaping the retail industry as an 18-year-old with only retail experience

Tags: work-environment, job-change, retail

For over two years now I have worked as a grocery store cashier. This is the only work environment I have ever known.

This year has taken a toll on a lot of people's mental health, my own included. Specifically, cloth masks are 'mandatory' in my hometown, and my choice not to wear one on medical grounds has been met with vicious backlash from customers and some coworkers. Many customers have demanded that another staff member call out management to punish me in some way. It's a good thing I spoke to management in advance (who took my side on the issue, as they had no real say in the matter anyway).

In general, I'm sick of being harassed and insulted by morbidly obese alcoholics and barely mobile 90-year-old women who treat shopping as a social event. I'm fed up with all my dedication and effort consistently going unrecognized. I need to try something completely new.

I think I need to escape the retail industry altogether.

The problem is, I'm fresh out of high school and just beginning to pursue my five-year degree in  Computer Science. I am taking this program because I am *not* "good with my hands", nor do I have any practical skill in what some would call "the trades", and therefore I am essentially doomed to work an office job for the rest of my life. Or am I? I also consider myself (as I'm sure is the unspoken consensus among those who have met me) a little slow on the uptake. Probably closer to autistic. For these reasons, I am afraid to make a change despite my unhealthy situation.

What kind of jobs should I look for? How do I change it up and escape retail for good?

Comment: `my choice not to wear one on medical grounds`..that's not really a _choice_ then, is it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh i think that OP means it's a choice he made based on some medical evidence they've seen, rather than actual medical grounds. At least that's how I've read it.

Comment: `therefore I am essentially doomed to work an office job for the rest of my life` -> Nope ! What you do with your life is (partly) up to you. You're only 18, don't believe that your choices now will lock you in some position for ever. When I was 18 I was in school, at 22 I was juggling in front of traffic lights all over EU, at 28 I was a farm worker, and now at 36 I'm making a CS PhD. Nothing is decided for ever if you don't decide it.

Comment: What were the "medical grounds" that made you "choose" not to wear a mask?

Comment: What does `a little slow on the uptake. Probably closer to autistic` mean specifically? Or is it just offensive to autistic people?

Comment: `as they had no real say in the matter anyway` that's not true, though.  They could almost certainly have fired you.  "Refuses to wear a mask" is not a protected class even if you aren't in a right-to-work state.

Comment: @BenBarden I cannot legally be punished in any way by my employers for being exempt from the order. That would constitute discrimination against employees with disabilities. A list of exemptions is implied by our human rights code and is supported by the local health unit responsible for the order.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I say 'choice' because many people claim to have serious health problems that would make them exempt from the order and still choose to wear a mask out of concern for their reputation. I suppose I too *could* wear a mask for five hours at a time, but I wouldn't be able to perform my job very well while having a claustrophobic attack every half hour. Technically, almost everything is a choice, but I see what you mean.

Comment: @gnasher729 Case in point. If you must know, I am claustrophobic, and cannot have anything near my face or neck. But is that really any of your concern? If you are implying the same question as Sourav, see my reply above.

Comment: @OmarL I mean that I often have trouble with seemingly basic tasks and sometimes with following instructions. I also find social interaction quite difficult. I'm not sure how perceiving similarities between oneself and the indicators of autism is offensive to autistic people. This is not a self-diagnosis.

Comment: @MicahWindsor It might be worth talking to a psychologist about if you have some sort of developmental disorder. Autism is a fairly broad category, after all, which is why the formal name for it now is “autistic spectrum disorder”. It’s also a lot harder to diagnose in adults, so it might be worth doing sooner rather than later.

Comment: When I was your age and starting college, I also didn't want to become an "office drone". But over time, my preferences changed. Office work is not as bad as [some people](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjJCdCXFslY) make it sound. Don't make drastic decisions today based off how much you "think" you will dislike a future work environment.

Comment: Are you looking for a job to work over the next 5 years until you complete your CS degree? [Good for you](https://www.bls.gov/ooh/computer-and-information-technology/home.htm). While you might not have very much "official" computer or IT experience at this point, that will slowly change over time as you get further along in your degree. If you are computer savvy and good on the phone, I would suggest looking into tech support telephone operator jobs at this point.

Answer (score 11):

Here are some things you might try:

- **Warehouse work.** No pesky customers, not a lot of skill required, and no learning curve. Depending on where you are, it might be abundantly available right now.
- **Delivery work.** There are customers, but not as much interaction with them and there is no particular skill required or a learning curve.
- **Security Guard.** While there are customers who are annoying, you have a bit more authority than as a cashier. People do not expect the guard to cater to their whims.
- **More selective retail.** A grocery store is probably the most likely place to attract crappy people as even grumpy people who would rather hide in their bedrooms like hibernating bears need groceries. A Lululemon might have kinder clients, if simply because the kind of people who shop there are more likely to have shame.
- **Freelance writing.** Not recommended if you need reliable or steady income, but it can compete with minimum wage jobs on average in annual income (emphasis on the "on average", as it is a cash management nightmare).

Comment: or go into the country, lots of easyish work, friendly people happy to see a new face, pays pretty good and the food's better quality.

Answer (score 4):

I am autistic as well, and I have done what you are trying to do.

The easiest way to jump ship is to gain experience in the area you want to move to.  The easiest way to get that experience is to do volunteer work.

I had a stroke at age 40 which left me unable to work for nearly five years.  As we all know, that's a lifetime in IT.  I started getting back in by doing volunteer support work for a hospital.

By doing volunteer work, you are not just building your experience, volunteer work also creates connections and networks to other people who may know where there are jobs for people with your talents.  You gain experience and contacts, as well as building your resume.  Volunteer work always looks good on a resume, and if you want to change careers, you need every advantage you can get.

Also, if you can, do some freelance work on the side.  Help friends and family with things they need, again to get experience and to gain good will.

Also, the book "What color is your parachute" is always good for inspiration.  Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You could try and get an **entry-level** IT job - these usually have low entry requirements. I did this part time whilst studying for my Electronic Engineering degree - not too dissimilar to your Computer Science degree you are about to study.

I worked mainly in hardware which meant that I was in an environment that mainly consisted of co-workers but occasionally had the odd customer meaning less chance of a conflict over your mask wearing choices. There was also an option to progress on to an IT Support type role which would then allow you to perhaps work remotely, depending on the company, further reducing your physical contact with customers.

Doing this work instead of a retail job definitely helped with some aspects of my degree and the two complimented each other well and I imagine they will for you too.

Your previous customer service skills are transferable here as sometimes you will have to deal with tricky customers - make sure you emphasise this if you get invited to an interview.

Another bonus of this is that you may even get offered a job to work for the company once you have completed your degree. The company I worked for had a software team which took on **Computer Science** students.

Comment: “You could try and get an entry-level IT job“ Nowadays those require both a university degree and five years experience, so hows he supposed to get one with neither?

Comment: I managed to get one with less retail experience than OP and before starting a, slightly, less relevant degree. There were also many others at the company I worked for in similar positions so it's definable not unreasonable.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you certainly don't appear *a little slow on the uptake*, even if that is your own opinion of yourself. For a start, you articulate very well.

> I'm fresh out of high school and just beginning to pursue my five-year
> degree

I am assuming you are a full-or-part-time student who needs an income. I understand you are already committed to this degree, but there are qualifications to get into IT which only take a few weeks or months of study, which may allow a career change sooner than 5 years.

> therefore I am essentially doomed to work an office job for the rest
> of my life

This is not an absolute. No one knows their future career.

> I am afraid to make a change despite my unhealthy situation

This is understandable, given the reasons you have stated. Universally, change is uncomfortable and for that reason it can be scary. Recognise that change will be uncomfortable. Accepting that may make things easier.

It sounds like you really need out of your current job, as it sounds borderline abusive.

> What kind of jobs should I look for?

I would say: Any job where you will not be singled out and victimised, and which pays enough for you to subsist on.

You are a student who needs an income while studying for a qualification. It doesn't really matter what industry you work in at the moment.

How much notice do you need to give? If you gave notice, it would certainly put some pressure on you to start looking for alternatives. This may not be possible depending on your financial situation.

> How do I change it up and escape retail for good?

It sounds like you only need to escape "front of house" retail. You could target other jobs in the retail sector, as you already have 2 years of relevant experience.